# How Can I write a byte created by bitSet to file?

Tags: java, fileoutputstream, bitset

Im creating a huffman compression program (in java) and I want to be able to write bits that are my encodings to file. e.g "65": "110".

First I'm trying to understand how I can use BitSet to write a byte with FileOutPutStream.

I've tried something like this but i doesn't work:

```
public class Test {


public static void main(String args[]){

    //constructor

    BitSet bs1 = new BitSet(8);

    // setting the bitset to 01000001
    bs1.set(1);
    bs1.set(7);


    byte[] b = bs1.toByteArray();


    /**
     * FileOutputStream to write the byte to file.
     * */


    try  {

        FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("test.txt");
        out.write(b);


    }catch (IOException e){

    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

I'm trying to write the ascii "A" to textfile.
I think the problem is that FileOutputStream.write() writes b.length bytes from the byte array to this file output stream.

And my byte is not 8 bits long , its 16 bits.

Comment: The byte array has `length` is `1` on my machine, and `write(byte[])` doesn't do anything unexpected. Can you double-check your observations?

Comment: BTW: you may want to just use `byte` and bitwise operators instead of `BitSet`

Comment: yes It has length of one as u say. its the bitSet bs1 that has size 16. I guess that doesn't matter. I expected my textfile test.txt to contain the ascii character "A" but opening the textfile with my IDE it just says: "loaded in the wrong endocing "UTF-8".  How can I use the byte with bitwise operations? @giorgiga

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op3.html

Comment: Thanks. If I wanted to write a byte to text file and when opening text file It would translate to "A". how would I do i Using my code? I know that "A" in ascii is 65 that is in bits: 01000001 ? @giorgiga

Comment: Err.. your code *does* write one byte to test.txt (however it writes 0x82 10000010 and not 0x41 01000001: BitSet indexes are zero-based).

Comment: @giorgiga okej,  I'm not understanding this. Is there a website describing this?

Comment: `BitSet` is described in the [API doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/index.html?java/util/BitSet.html), as is `FileOutputStream`... IDK if that helps or not (I guess you already read the java doc)

Comment: if you want to write "a" into a test.txt, there are easier ways :) ..and "the problem" I see, is that you "not agree with output", but the main thing is: you do the writing not bad, and you could *restore* your bit set from (exactly this) file:  `FileInputStream fIn = new FileInputStream("test.txt");
            BitSet bs2 = BitSet.valueOf(fIn.readAllBytes());
            System.out.println(bs2.toString());`